# UWP MediaElement source from http with authentication

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, mediaelement

Is there a way to use a MediaElement Control, to stream e.g. a video or audio file from a remote (web)server, which needs authentication for accessing? To access this server, i am using Windows.Web.HttpClient, but i dont know how to easily access the source with a MediaElement.

Best regards

Comment: You can first authenticate from your app to get the video/audio's url in the server, how to authentication, it depends on your server. And it's easy to use MediaElement to play a url source. For example: `mediaElement.Source = new Uri("...");`, "mediaElement" here is the name of `MediaElement` control.

Comment: Thank you. You mean i can connect to my Server with HttpClient and set the mediaElement.Source... from my HttpClients URI?

Comment: No, the source should be the video/audio's url. It should be different from your server's uri.

Comment: I dont unterstand that. As an example, the URI to my videofile is https://myserver.com/myvideo.mkv. Now myserver.com needs authentication, so i connect with HttpClient, but with which method? You said i need to get the URI, then there is a property in the HttpClient to get the URI to my server, with this i can access the videofile?

Comment: The popular way now to do it is sending a request to server, in the header of this request, you need to add the login info into it, when success, server will response you with a access token, you can save this token in your app, and when you play the video/audio, the url should contain the access token.But it most depends on your server, not every server works in this parrtern. For example you can refer to [Authentication Scenarios for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/) to see the procedure of Azure AD.

Comment: Ok i see. But my server does not work with such a token. The authentication goes over digest auth, it is a webdav server.

Comment: if it's basic auth you can try using the inline authentication protocol: http://user:pass@myserver.com/myvideo.mkv

Comment: @Grace Feng, I have done it now by first authenticate on my Server and now i can stream the Video. I have another question related to the MediaElement, is there a way to handle additional actions, if one of the MediaControls (e.g. Stop) is pressed? And is it possible to set the size of the poster image?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the stream from buffering, if stop is pressed?