# UWP MediaSource with authentication via HTTP

Tags: c#, authentication, video, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to stream a video from a webserver via HTTP. To stream the video I currently create a MediaSource:

```
MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("https://example.com/video.mp4"));
```

And then I add that MediaSource to my MediaPlayerElement and the video plays.

This works as long as the server does not need authentication. But now I have a server which uses Basic auth so the video does not start.

My old requests looked similar to this

`GET /video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Range: bytes=0-
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.00.15063.0332 WMFSDK/12.00.15063.0332
GetContentFeatures.DLNA.ORG: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: example.com
Connection: Keep-Alive enter code here`

Now I need them to also have an Authentication Header, but I dont know how to achieve that (because I can't use my own HttpClient):

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

I found this question [UWP MediaElement source from http with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37540437/uwp-mediaelement-source-from-http-with-authentication) which is similar to my problem. The author solved his problem, but unfortunately did not exactly describe how he did it.

Can someone help here? How can I get the MediaSource or the MediaPlayerElement to use credentials/basic auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, [MediaSource.CreateFromUri(Uri)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Core.MediaSource#Windows_Media_Core_MediaSource_CreateFromUri_Windows_Foundation_Uri_) method can only accept a `Uri` parameter, there is no way to set Authentication Header with this method.

To play a online video file that requires authentication, we can take advantage of `HttpClient` which can make HTTP requests with required credentials or headers manually.

And then we may also need a custom [IRandomAccessStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream) class that builds on top of `HttpClient`, so we could use range headers to request just a sequence of bytes from the server and would not need to download the whole file in order to stream it.

For more info, you can refer to [MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient) on GitHub, which implements a [HttpRandomAccessStream class](https://github.com/kiewic/MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient/blob/master/MediaPlayerElementWithHttpClient/HttpRandomAccessStream.cs).

> The `HttpRandomAccessStream` class is a wrapper on top of [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient.aspx) that can stream content from the internet and can be consumed as an `IRandomAcessStream` or `IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType`.

And when using above solution, please note: **The server must support HTTP [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5) headers.**